# Spring Boot - Injecting Repository into Controller throws Consider defining a bean of type 'Type' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, dependency-injection

I have a Spring/Boot REST controller which I inject a repository into like so:

```java
package com.example.schooltimetable.controllers;

import com.example.schooltimetable.models.entities.StudentEntity;
import com.example.schooltimetable.repository.StudentRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("student")
public class StudentController {

    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Iterable<StudentEntity> getAllStudents() {
        return this.studentRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that whenever i start my application it throws the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.schooltimetable.controllers.StudentController required a bean of type 'com.example.schooltimetable.repository.StudentsRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.schooltimetable.repository.StudentsRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I faced this issue before when trying to find an Entity in another class, I fixed this by using the `@ComponentScan()` annotation in `Application.java`, however, it doesn't work to fix this issue.

My main application file looks like this:

SchoolTimetableApplication

```java
package com.example.schooltimetable;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({
    "com.example.schooltimetable.controllers",
    "org.springframework.stereotype",
    "com.example.schooltimetable.repository",
})
public class SchoolTimetableApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchoolTimetableApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And my repository looks like this:
StudentRepository

```java
package com.example.schooltimetable.repository;

import com.example.schooltimetable.models.entities.StudentEntity;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@Component
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<StudentEntity, Long> { }
```

The StudentEntity referenced in the repository:

```java
package com.example.schooltimetable.models.entities;

import com.example.schooltimetable.models.constants.StudentEntityConstants;
import com.example.schooltimetable.models.constants.TimetableEntityConstants;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = StudentEntityConstants.TABLE_NAME)
public class StudentEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = StudentEntityConstants.ID)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = StudentEntityConstants.FIRST_NAME)
    @NonNull
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = StudentEntityConstants.LAST_NAME)
    @NonNull
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = StudentEntityConstants.REFERENCE)
    @NonNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID reference;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = TimeTableEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = TimetableEntityConstants.REFERENCE)
    private TimeTableEntity timeTable;

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public UUID getReference() {
        return this.reference;
    }

    public void setReference(UUID reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    public TimeTableEntity getTimeTable() {
        return this.timeTable;
    }
}
```

And my POM file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>school-timetable</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>school-timetable</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Is there something I've done wrong? I'm very new to Spring/Boot. An interesting note with this issue is that if I remove

```
@ComponentScan({
    "com.example.schooltimetable.controllers", <---- This
    "org.springframework.stereotype",
    "com.example.schooltimetable.repository",
})
```

Then the application loads but the controller will throw a 404 when trying to hit: `http://localhost:8080/student/getAll`

**EDIT!!!**

There was a few things wrong with the application at this point.
Firstly, the POM file needed updating

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>school-timetable</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>school-timetable</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Secondly, the MAIN CLASS

```
package com.example.schooltimetable;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EntityScan("com.example.schooltimetable.models.entities")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.schooltimetable.repository")
public class SchoolTimetableApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchoolTimetableApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

There were also things wrong with the entities when joining columns: They should be set to read and write: false

```java
package com.example.schooltimetable.models.entities;

import com.example.schooltimetable.models.constants.StudentEntityConstants;
import com.example.schooltimetable.models.constants.TimetableEntityConstants;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = StudentEntityConstants.TABLE_NAME)
public class StudentEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = StudentEntityConstants.ID)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = StudentEntityConstants.FIRST_NAME)
    @NonNull
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = StudentEntityConstants.LAST_NAME)
    @NonNull
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = StudentEntityConstants.REFERENCE)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID reference;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = TimeTableEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = TimetableEntityConstants.REFERENCE, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private TimeTableEntity timeTable;

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public UUID getReference() {
        return this.reference;
    }

    public void setReference(UUID reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    public TimeTableEntity getTimeTable() {
        return this.timeTable;
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Abhinaba Chakraborty for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Your proposed solution is not the solution but a workaround. You don't need all those annotatons, only the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation should do it. Your depenendcies remove the `spring-data-commons`, `spring-data-jpa` and `hibernate` dpeendencies and instead add a single `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` which includes all of those.

Comment: @M.Deinum You're spot on. The proposed solution was a workaround, I've since refactored it and fixed it, I'm working on posting the answer now! Long week 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED!!!**

So the problem was with the way I'd implemented the `@OneToOne` relationship between the student and the Timetable.

The edit in the question was a work around as stated by @M.Deinum. The correct solution was to first clean up the relationship between Student and Timetable, like so:

`StudentEntity`

```
package com.example.schooltimetable.models.entities;

import com.example.schooltimetable.models.constants.StudentEntityConstants;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = StudentEntityConstants.TABLE_NAME)
public class StudentEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = StudentEntityConstants.ID)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = StudentEntityConstants.FIRST_NAME)
    @NonNull
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = StudentEntityConstants.LAST_NAME)
    @NonNull
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // no need to join the columns on the Student. 
    private TimeTableEntity timeTable;

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public TimeTableEntity getTimeTable() {
        return this.timeTable;
    }

    public void setTimeTable(TimeTableEntity timeTable) { this.timeTable = timeTable; }
}
```

`TimeTableEntity`

```
package com.example.schooltimetable.models.entities;

import com.example.schooltimetable.models.constants.TimetableEntityConstants;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = TimetableEntityConstants.TABLE_NAME)
public class TimeTableEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = TimetableEntityConstants.ID)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId // <-- This automatically knows to join by the student ID column
    private StudentEntity student;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private final Set<ModuleEntity> modules = new LinkedHashSet();

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setStudent(StudentEntity student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public Set<ModuleEntity> getModules() {
        return this.modules;
    }

    public void setModules(ModuleEntity module) {
        this.modules.add(module);
    }
}
```

Now, the next few refactors, I could just do, I don't know why it worked all of a sudden but I have a feeling it was to do with the bad entity setup.I was able to remove the
`@EntityScan("com.example.schooltimetable.models.entities") & @EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.schooltimetable.repository")`

Annotations from my main class, and I was also able to remove a lot of `@Scope` and `@Component` annotations from my code. My main class now looks like this:

`SchoolTimetableApplication`

```
package com.example.schooltimetable;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SchoolTimetableApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchoolTimetableApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Much better! I also have data pulling through for the relationships rather than `null` (another issue I was facing).

Answer (score 3):

First of all , you don't need a component scan with the annotation **SpringBootApplication** in place. Spring automatically scans all components annotated with Component,Service,RestController,Respository,Configuration etc. and creates the Beans.

The request mapping annotation value in StudentController should be prefixed with "/" eg. @RequestMapping("/student") - Although it has nothing to do with dependency injection . But this is the reason why you are getting a 404 at http://localhost:8080/student/getAll

In the repository interface, just use @Repository annotation instead of having both @Repository and @Component annotations.

Also I dont see a data-jpa dependency defined in your POM.xml yet How are you importing the **org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository** in your repository. You need that dependency.

As far as directory structure concerned, it looks OK ,but please verify:

[image]

Comment: Yeah that's correct in terms of the folder structure and I now get this: 

I've stripped out the ```@component``` from ```StudentRepository```, taken the ```@ComponentScan``` out of ```SchoolTimetableApplication```, installed the data-jpa dependency. 

```org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentRepository' defined in com.example.schooltimetable.repository.StudentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories ```

Comment: Do you have these properties defined in application yaml:
spring.jpa.database-platform: XXX
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: none etc

Comment: I have this:

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= none
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils=debug